# IE9: page not responding. Sometimes

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My client has encountered a problem where two sites will randomly not load in IE9.

Apparently it seems to hang and then produce a IE message saying "*superhomewifi.com is not responding*". The page is blank when the message shows, followed by another MS error message saying *The page is not responding and needs to be closed*.

The sites are http://superhomewifi.com/ and http://superyachtwifi.com/.

I'm not able to reproduce the error, so I'm hoping somebody here can at least have a look at the links and see if the same error appears. You might have to reload the page a few times to force the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of reverse engineering and a lot of searches I've come to the conclusion that it is a bug that appears when using selectivizr.js *and* @font-face at the same time. I haven't found any solutions besides leaving out one or the other.

I never managed to reproduce the error in IE9, but did get similar errors in IE8 and IE7, so I did my debugging from there.